# find url in a string using typescript : anchor tag displayed as plain text

Tags: html, typescript, url, hyperlink

I am trying to find the URL in a given text using typescript and if its the URL, then I have to make it as hyperlink.
I used the code from one of the stackoverflow links.

I have tried the below code :

```
Urlify(text) {
    var exp = /(\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|(www))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]*)/ig; 
    var res = text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
    console.log("res : ", res); 
    return res;
}
```

However, I am not able to see it as an URL in browser.  It looks like below :

> Hi the line is <a href='www.google.com.'>www.google.com.</a> End of line.

Instead of

> Hi the line is [www.google.om](http://www.google.om). End of line.

Why am I seeing the "a href" in browser ? Am I missing anything ?
Please help.

Comment: if i copy and paste that code and execute it, it works on my system. are you sure you are call the method? The regexp includes the trailing . but that is not the question, is it?

Comment: yeah, I am calling the method and the anchor tag is seen as plain text on front end. Pls let me know if I am missing anything. The code I gave above is used in typescript code and html page shows the anchor tag on screen instead of hyperlinking.